# What is the C++ key scan code for the "Windows" button?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for the "Windows" button key scan code to emulate a key press. What is the scan code?

I looked through *[Key Scan Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)* and totally don’t have any idea which one is the hexadecimal scan code for it...

I'm looking for the hardware scan code to emulate a physical key press for the "Windows" button.

Comment: Write code to read the scan codes.  Press the button.

Comment: `e0 5b` - http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html

Comment: you were searching the right database, but looking at the wrong page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx (or search for virtual key codes)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was looking for Hardware Scan Code but I think I know what to do now since you all gave me an idea how to do it.  
    UINT uCode = MapVirtualKey(VK_LWIN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);  
  
  Not sure if it works or not but I will test it later.

Comment: Yes, it isn't easy to find. Keywords like `right Windows key scan code` are too generic. [It is](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/08/29/controlling-leds-on-ps-2-keyboards/): *"The Microsoft keyboard adds 0xE0 0x5B (LeftWindow), 0xE0 0x5C (RightWindow), and 0xE0 0x5D (Menu)"*. Note that that probably only covers ***pressing*** the left Windows key. The ***release*** key sequence may or may not be different.

Comment: Though empirically, ***it seems to be 0x1F (31), not 0x5B (91)***... Both with Microsoft "[Natural Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Natural_keyboard#Natural_Keyboard)" and USB keyboard 'Altar' model 103008 working in PS/2 mode. Definitely working in PS/2 mode - direct connection to standard I/O pins, using hardware async serial for supporting the decoding (yes, it is possible if the baud rate is known). Perhaps they did a bad copy-paste?

Comment: In other words, it seems to be the scan code sequence 0xE0 0x1F (LeftWindow key).

Comment: For the right Windows key: 0xE0 0x27. For the context menu key: 0xE0 0x2F. Both empirically.

Comment: Is it different for PS/2?

Comment: Are there some duplicate questions? This was posted near 7 years after Stack Overflow launched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that VK_LWIN (0x5B) is the left Windows key and VK_RWIN (0x5C) is the right Windows key.

Please look at *[List of Virtual Key Codes](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html)*:

```
Name                    Numeric value   Description
---------------------------------------------------
VK_ABNT_C1              0xC1            Abnt C1
VK_ABNT_C2              0xC2            Abnt C2
VK_ADD                  0x6B            Numpad +
VK_ATTN                 0xF6            Attn
VK_BACK                 0x08            Backspace
VK_CANCEL               0x03            Break
VK_CLEAR                0x0C            Clear
VK_CRSEL                0xF7            Cr Sel
VK_DECIMAL              0x6E            Numpad .
VK_DIVIDE               0x6F            Numpad /
VK_EREOF                0xF9            Er Eof
VK_ESCAPE               0x1B            Esc
VK_EXECUTE              0x2B            Execute
VK_EXSEL                0xF8            Ex Sel
VK_ICO_CLEAR            0xE6            IcoClr
VK_ICO_HELP             0xE3            IcoHlp
VK_KEY_0                0x30            ('0')    0
VK_KEY_1                0x31            ('1')    1
VK_KEY_2                0x32            ('2')    2
VK_KEY_3                0x33            ('3')    3
VK_KEY_4                0x34            ('4')    4
VK_KEY_5                0x35            ('5')    5
VK_KEY_6                0x36            ('6')    6
VK_KEY_7                0x37            ('7')    7
VK_KEY_8                0x38            ('8')    8
VK_KEY_9                0x39            ('9')    9
VK_KEY_A                0x41            ('A')    A
VK_KEY_B                0x42            ('B')    B
VK_KEY_C                0x43            ('C')    C
VK_KEY_D                0x44            ('D')    D
VK_KEY_E                0x45            ('E')    E
VK_KEY_F                0x46            ('F')    F
VK_KEY_G                0x47            ('G')    G
VK_KEY_H                0x48            ('H')    H
VK_KEY_I                0x49            ('I')    I
VK_KEY_J                0x4A            ('J')    J
VK_KEY_K                0x4B            ('K')    K
VK_KEY_L                0x4C            ('L')    L
VK_KEY_M                0x4D            ('M')    M
VK_KEY_N                0x4E            ('N')    N
VK_KEY_O                0x4F            ('O')    O
VK_KEY_P                0x50            ('P')    P
VK_KEY_Q                0x51            ('Q')    Q
VK_KEY_R                0x52            ('R')    R
VK_KEY_S                0x53            ('S')    S
VK_KEY_T                0x54            ('T')    T
VK_KEY_U                0x55            ('U')    U
VK_KEY_V                0x56            ('V')    V
VK_KEY_W                0x57            ('W')    W
VK_KEY_X                0x58            ('X')    X
VK_KEY_Y                0x59            ('Y')    Y
VK_KEY_Z                0x5A            ('Z')    Z
VK_MULTIPLY             0x6A            Numpad *
VK_NONAME               0xFC            NoName
VK_NUMPAD0              0x60            Numpad 0
VK_NUMPAD1              0x61            Numpad 1
VK_NUMPAD2              0x62            Numpad 2
VK_NUMPAD3              0x63            Numpad 3
VK_NUMPAD4              0x64            Numpad 4
VK_NUMPAD5              0x65            Numpad 5
VK_NUMPAD6              0x66            Numpad 6
VK_NUMPAD7              0x67            Numpad 7
VK_NUMPAD8              0x68            Numpad 8
VK_NUMPAD9              0x69            Numpad 9
VK_OEM_1                0xBA            OEM_1 (: ;)
VK_OEM_102              0xE2            OEM_102 (> <)
VK_OEM_2                0xBF            OEM_2 (? /)
VK_OEM_3                0xC0            OEM_3 (~ `)
VK_OEM_4                0xDB            OEM_4 ({ [)
VK_OEM_5                0xDC            OEM_5 (| \)
VK_OEM_6                0xDD            OEM_6 (} ])
VK_OEM_7                0xDE            OEM_7 (" ')
VK_OEM_8                0xDF            OEM_8 (§ !)
VK_OEM_ATTN             0xF0            Oem Attn
VK_OEM_AUTO             0xF3            Auto
VK_OEM_AX               0xE1            Ax
VK_OEM_BACKTAB          0xF5            Back Tab
VK_OEM_CLEAR            0xFE            OemClr
VK_OEM_COMMA            0xBC            OEM_COMMA (< ,)
VK_OEM_COPY             0xF2            Copy
VK_OEM_CUSEL            0xEF            Cu Sel
VK_OEM_ENLW             0xF4            Enlw
VK_OEM_FINISH           0xF1            Finish
VK_OEM_FJ_LOYA          0x95            Loya
VK_OEM_FJ_MASSHOU       0x93            Mashu
VK_OEM_FJ_ROYA          0x96            Roya
VK_OEM_FJ_TOUROKU       0x94            Touroku
VK_OEM_JUMP             0xEA            Jump
VK_OEM_MINUS            0xBD            OEM_MINUS (_ -)
VK_OEM_PA1              0xEB            OemPa1
VK_OEM_PA2              0xEC            OemPa2
VK_OEM_PA3              0xED            OemPa3
VK_OEM_PERIOD           0xBE            OEM_PERIOD (> .)
VK_OEM_PLUS             0xBB            OEM_PLUS (+ =)
VK_OEM_RESET            0xE9            Reset
VK_OEM_WSCTRL           0xEE            WsCtrl
VK_PA1                  0xFD            Pa1
VK_PACKET               0xE7            Packet
VK_PLAY                 0xFA            Play
VK_PROCESSKEY           0xE5            Process
VK_RETURN               0x0D            Enter
VK_SELECT               0x29            Select
VK_SEPARATOR            0x6C            Separator
VK_SPACE                0x20            Space
VK_SUBTRACT             0x6D            Num -
VK_TAB                  0x09            Tab
VK_ZOOM                 0xFB            Zoom
VK__none_               0xFF            no VK mapping
VK_ACCEPT               0x1E            Accept
VK_APPS                 0x5D            Context Menu
VK_BROWSER_BACK         0xA6            Browser Back
VK_BROWSER_FAVORITES    0xAB            Browser Favorites
VK_BROWSER_FORWARD      0xA7            Browser Forward
VK_BROWSER_HOME         0xAC            Browser Home
VK_BROWSER_REFRESH      0xA8            Browser Refresh
VK_BROWSER_SEARCH       0xAA            Browser Search
VK_BROWSER_STOP         0xA9            Browser Stop
VK_CAPITAL              0x14            Caps Lock
VK_CONVERT              0x1C            Convert
VK_DELETE               0x2E            Delete
VK_DOWN                 0x28            Arrow Down
VK_END                  0x23            End
VK_F1                   0x70            F1
VK_F10                  0x79            F10
VK_F11                  0x7A            F11
VK_F12                  0x7B            F12
VK_F13                  0x7C            F13
VK_F14                  0x7D            F14
VK_F15                  0x7E            F15
VK_F16                  0x7F            F16
VK_F17                  0x80            F17
VK_F18                  0x81            F18
VK_F19                  0x82            F19
VK_F2                   0x71            F2
VK_F20                  0x83            F20
VK_F21                  0x84            F21
VK_F22                  0x85            F22
VK_F23                  0x86            F23
VK_F24                  0x87            F24
VK_F3                   0x72            F3
VK_F4                   0x73            F4
VK_F5                   0x74            F5
VK_F6                   0x75            F6
VK_F7                   0x76            F7
VK_F8                   0x77            F8
VK_F9                   0x78            F9
VK_FINAL                0x18            Final
VK_HELP                 0x2F            Help
VK_HOME                 0x24            Home
VK_ICO_00               0xE4            Ico00 *
VK_INSERT               0x2D            Insert
VK_JUNJA                0x17            Junja
VK_KANA                 0x15            Kana
VK_KANJI                0x19            Kanji
VK_LAUNCH_APP1          0xB6            App1
VK_LAUNCH_APP2          0xB7            App2
VK_LAUNCH_MAIL          0xB4            Mail
VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT  0xB5            Media
VK_LBUTTON              0x01            Left Button **
VK_LCONTROL             0xA2            Left Ctrl
VK_LEFT                 0x25            Arrow Left
VK_LMENU                0xA4            Left Alt
VK_LSHIFT               0xA0            Left Shift
VK_LWIN                 0x5B            Left Win
VK_MBUTTON              0x04            Middle Button **
VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK     0xB0            Next Track
VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE     0xB3            Play / Pause
VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK     0xB1            Previous Track
VK_MEDIA_STOP           0xB2            Stop
VK_MODECHANGE           0x1F            Mode Change
VK_NEXT                 0x22            Page Down
VK_NONCONVERT           0x1D            Non Convert
VK_NUMLOCK              0x90            Num Lock
VK_OEM_FJ_JISHO         0x92            Jisho
VK_PAUSE                0x13            Pause
VK_PRINT                0x2A            Print
VK_PRIOR                0x21            Page Up
VK_RBUTTON              0x02            Right Button **
VK_RCONTROL             0xA3            Right Ctrl
VK_RIGHT                0x27            Arrow Right
VK_RMENU                0xA5            Right Alt
VK_RSHIFT               0xA1            Right Shift
VK_RWIN                 0x5C            Right Win
VK_SCROLL               0x91            Scrol Lock
VK_SLEEP                0x5F            Sleep
VK_SNAPSHOT             0x2C            Print Screen
VK_UP                   0x26            Arrow Up
VK_VOLUME_DOWN          0xAE            Volume Down
VK_VOLUME_MUTE          0xAD            Volume Mute
VK_VOLUME_UP            0xAF            Volume Up
VK_XBUTTON1             0x05            X Button 1 **
VK_XBUTTON2             0x06            X Button 2 **
```

Comment: OP asked for scancode and you answered with virtual keys.
Scancode is hardware, Virtualkey is "virtual" / OS dependent etc...
If a vegetarian asks for food, you dont give him meat.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer, even if it was accepted (it shouldn't have been).

Answer (score 1):

`VK_LWIN` is part of the 'Extended Scan Codes' and as such the `MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX` is needed for `MapVirtualKey` to return the correct result - as Brian commented the correct scan code is `e0 5b`.

If using `SendInput` with scan codes for the `Win` key your `KEYBDINPUT` needs to include the `KEYEVENTF.EXTENDEDKEY` flag as well as the `KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE` flag.

It would look like this for a key down event:

```
KEYBDINPUT kbdInput = new KEYBDINPUT()
{
    wVk = 0,
    wScan = 0xE05B, // Or use MapVirtualKey(VK_LWIN, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX)
    dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYDOWN | KEYEVENTF.EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE),
    time = 0,
    dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo()
}
```

Note that the `KEYEVENTF.EXTENDEDKEY` flag for keyboard events will stop non-extended key scan codes (i.e. the alphanumeric keys) from behaving normally.

You can determine if the key requires this flag for the keyboard event by checking if the output of `MapVirtualKey` has a `E0` prefix.

Disclaimer: Not a C++ developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MapVirtualKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya) to map virtual key codes, like `VK_LWIN` and `VK_RWIN`, into scan codes, and vice versa.